# perl search and append

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a perl one-liner to search for a string q(abc* and append to it when that string is found. My input file has a bunch of things like this:

```
q(abc0x[...
q(abc1x[...
q(abc2x[...
q(abc0y[...
```

I would like the output to be:

```
q(abc0x_str[...
q(abc1x_str[...
q(abc2x_str[...
q(abc0y_str[...
```

I've tried this:

```
perl -pi -e "s/(q\((abc\S+)\[)/\$1_str\1/" file
```

but the `$1` backreference seems to pick up the value from my environment when I type `echo $1` and pre-pends `_str` instead of appending it, giving this output:

```
-project_strq(abc0x[...
```

where `$1` just happens to be "-project" in my environment.

Alternatively, I've tried:

```
perl -pi -e "s/(q\(abc\S+)\[)/_str\1/" file
```

but the output here looks like this instead with the pre-pended `_str`:

```
_strq(abc0x[...
```

Neither output is what I expect. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces your desired output:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(q\(abc\S+)\[/$1_str[/' file
```

As you noticed, the shell interprets $1 as a shell variable.  You need to use single quotes to prevent the shell from treating it as a variable.

The one-liner you originally posted generates an error for me (I see you have now edited your original code).

Answer (score 0):

$1 is interpreted by bash because you quote your perl code inside "...". Replace your one-liner with:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(q\(abc\S+)\[)/$1_str[/' file
```

Like in Perl, single-quotes wont interpret the content.

I also fixed `\1`, replacing it with `[`.